# JQuery UI Autocomplete is not returning any results to the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the `JQuery UI` Autocomplete Widget to show suggested searches to users as they type into my search bar. However I'm getting a problem whereby the results are not appearing to the user as they type.

This is my `script`:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){  
        $j("#tag_search").autocomplete({                        
            source:'autocomplete_tags.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            minLength:1
    });
});
```

This is the `autocomplete_tags.php`:

```
require_once '../includes/preheader.php';//connects to db
$term = $_GET["term"];//Get the search terms. 

//Select tags from the database based on the specified search keyword
 $query  = "SELECT * FROM tag WHERE NAME LIKE '".$term."%' ORDER BY NAME ASC";
 $json=array();

 $db->query($query);//Query the DB.

 //Parse through the results and store in an array
 while($db->next()){
    $json[]=array(
            'id' => $db->get('id'),
            'value'=>$db->get("name"),
            'label'=>$db->get("description")
    );
 }
 //Autocomplete JQuery UI expects a Json Array so encode and echo. 
 echo json_encode($json);
```

If I visit this url I can see a `json` array in the browser with the results, which makes me believe that it is working as it should, but for some reason the results are not showing.

```
http://my-site.tld/includes/autocomplete_tags.php?term=ag
```

Output:

```
[{"id":"29","value":"Agriculture","label":"This is a tag about agriculture and farming"}]
```

Also, I've checked in my console that the file is being found correctly when the user is typing and I am getting a `200`  response code.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? I've implemented a similar feature on another site and it worked no problem. Could it be a styling issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, very stupid of me not to realise this but rather than deleting the question, for anyone else who might be trying to do the same thing you must make sure that you include the `jquery-ui` `css` file. Just place this in the header of your site:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

In terms of my post above, all the code was correct and working as it should, the only thing missing was the above stylesheet.